# Custom Airplay button with cocoalibspotify

Tags: cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm using SPPlaybackManager and i saw that there is support in Airplay , but i can't find any function that activate the airplay , the only support i see is when i press the home button twice swiping right till i see the airplay button.

is there any way i could make an custom button on my view that when i press on it it will pop up all the NEAR-BY devices using cocoalibspotify?

i saw it is possible with MPVolumeView... but nothing with spotify.

will appreciate if any of you fellows could direct me a bit cause i try to search and didn't found nothing about this subject.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPVolumeView` is the thing to use - the AirPlay setting is system-wide. As such, there's nothing in CocoaLibSpotify specifically to do with AirPlay.

Comment: thanks, was i've did some trick to get only the airplay button works great